# Socket C++: Client Error after press F5

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

I'm coding socket C++ in visual studio 2017. 
2 solutions represent for Server & Client. 
When I build Client solution, process is success. But after I press F5, it has a error that I can't understand.
This is the code of Client solution: http://codepad.org/bWDvyypu
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks,

[Errors that I meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvL8h.png)

Comment: *What* "error"? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (to show *in the question itself*).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the library you are using, but given the runtime exception that is thrown, and given your code, I would say that here is the problem:

```
client.Receive((char*)temp.c_str(), length, 0);
```

Because this method tries to write on temp.c_str(), that is a const ([std::string.c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the anti-virus programs can block it. Try disabling anti-virus program.